# Has anyone tried to bake raw olives?

Tags: olive

I was thinking about alternative ways of processing olives. 
Has anyone tried to bake raw olives? What did it look and taste like?

Comment: when you say 'raw' are you talking about before they've been cured?  (brined or salted).  Because this step is also referred to as 'debittering'.  (ie, they're really bitter when fresh off the tree)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean :)

Comment: Raw olives are quite bitter because they contain [Oleuropein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleuropein).